# I can't make calls on Skype

Tags: 14.04

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Now I am unable to make calls on Skype. Every time it shows call failed. How can I rectify the error?

Comment: check your skype version, skype v4.2 is out of support.

Comment: This may not exactly deals with Ubuntu! but Problem/Support from Skype (Application-Specific) and further if related than bug-reporting.